# For raid1, does btrfs check which partitions are on the same device?

Tags: partitioning, raid, btrfs

I have btrfs on two partitions using btrfs's raid1 mode:

```
/dev/sda3
/dev/sdb3
```

Now I plan to run `btrfs device add /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2`, so I'll have four partitions:

```
/dev/sda2 /dev/sda3
/dev/sdb2 /dev/sdb3
```

My question: will btrfs know that sda2 and sda3 are the same disk, so it shouldn't mirror data between those two?

(I realize it's a bit silly to have two partitions on each disk, but I already have data on the filesystem and this seems the fastest way to add space.)

The closest thing I could find to an answer is a project idea from the wiki concerned with devices on the same controller: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Project_ideas#Chunk_allocation_groups .  It almost seems to imply this already happens for devices, but this might just be wishful thinking on my part.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, these will all be luks-encrypted, so the actual btrfs devices will be /dev/dm-[0123] or some such.  But I'm curious to know the answer with or without the encryption layer.

Comment: Did you have any progress?

Comment: No, I don't know the answer. I don't remember how I added the extra space, but right now I still only have one partition on each disk.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a Btrfs with multiple devices or add more devices later on, Btrfs won't care if those are partitions of a single storage device or they're multiple storage devices, no matter what allocation profile (i.e. *raid{0,1,10,5,6,...},dup,single*) you use.

If you add `/dev/sd{a,b}2` to your existing *Btrfs* setup, then *RAID1* redundancy can't be effectively achieved because the mirrored blocks could get written to either combination of  `/dev/sd{a,b}{2,3}`. If they got written to the same storage device, then write would take ~2x time and single storage device failure will take away both good copies.

Creating Btrfs on top of *dm-crypt* devices doesn't effect redundancy.

See the [Btrfs manual](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/mkfs.btrfs) for more info, 
 and the warning: **it is not recommended to use *RAID* profiles with partitions of same storage device, Neither redundancy nor performance will be increased**.

Comment: It also states "The mkfs utility will let the user create a filesystem with profiles that write the logical blocks to 2 physical locations. Whether there are really 2 physical copies highly depends on the underlying device type." https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mkfs.btrfs.html#man-mkfs-dup-profiles-on-a-single-device